# Static analysis errors when Creating Table

Tags: mysql

I am currently having some trouble creating my table for my database. I'm not sure what I'm missing and if anyone can help me figure this out, that'd be great!

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Krenko (Name VARCHAR(50), Quantity INT(3), Price DOUBLE(20), Own INT(3), Need INT(3));
```

Error:

```
Static analysis:

5 errors were found during analysis.

    A symbol name was expected! (near "Name" at position 21)
    At least one column definition was expected. (near "Name" at position 21)
    Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "50" at position 34)
    Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Quantity" at position 39)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "INT" at position 48)
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Krenko (Name VARCHAR(50), Quantity INT(3), Price DOUBLE(20), Own INT(3), Need INT(3))
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), Own INT(3), Need INT(3))' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You are defining data type of `Price` in wrong way. Instead of DOUBLE(20), use `DOUBLE(20,5)`.

In mysql, DOUBLE data type needs 0 or 2(length, decimal places) parameters. If 0 parameters is provided, default 16,4 is taken. Read [more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)

Try following query:

```
CREATE TABLE Krenko (
  Name VARCHAR(50), 
  Quantity INT(3), 
  Price DOUBLE(20, 5), 
  Own INT(3), 
  Need INT(3)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the declaration of your price colum double. If you want to specifie the digits, it has to be in the form: DOUBLE(M,D). 
 Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

```
CREATE TABLE Krenko (Name VARCHAR(50), Quantity INT(3), Price DOUBLE(20,2), 
Own INT(3), Need INT(3));
```

An other solution to your problem is to remove the specification of the number of digits.

```
CREATE TABLE Krenko (Name VARCHAR(50), Quantity INT(3), Price DOUBLE, Own 
INT(3), Need INT(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (
    'username ' varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    'password' varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    'email' varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    'level' ENUM('admin','user') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
    'blokir' ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    'id_sesions'varchar (50) NOT NULL
)    ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).